# Imprimir datos JSON como texto de HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json

Estoy trabajando en una practica de *cURL*, que regresa un archivo *JSON* y que necesito imprimir en mi página principal (si se pudiera, como un enlace). Sé que este archivo se tiene que mandar llamar con *javascript*. Creo que yo ya tengo el archivo *JSON* creado por medio de este código:

```
 $json_string = json_encode($arreglo);
 $file = 'datos.json';
 file_put_contents($file, $json_string);
 echo $json_string;
 echo '<br>';
```

Soy nuevo en esto me estoy guiando con tutoriales, pero me piden que lo mande a *frontend* por medio del método *POST*. Si ya tengo el archivo creado, ¿cómo quedaría la siguiente estructura?

A la hora de ejecutarlo me marca error en la consola.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET','api.php');
xhr.onload = function(){
    if(xhr.status==200){
        var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(json);
    } else{
        console.log("Existe un error de tipo: " + xhr.status);
    }
}
xhr.send();
```

Comment: ¿Qué error recibes en la consola? Por favor, edita la pregunta para agregar el mensaje. Por cierto, te lo piden por método _POST_ y estás haciendo la petición por _GET_.

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de ver un par de detalles.
El archivo que has creado es datos.json, pero tu lees el api.php. No sería mucho problema porque api.php se supone que devuelve la cadena JSON.
Sea como sea el objeto xhr **no está leyendo un archivo htm**, sino un archivo de texto. El código de resultado no es el mismo, no debes comparar con 200 sino con 0.
Así que la respuesta para evitar el error es cambiar el condicional en lugar de comparar xhr.status con 200 compara con 0

```
if(xhr.status==0){ ...
```

Espero que esa solución se útil

Comment: Esto parece más un comentario que una respuesta y, de hecho, no importa el tipo de recurso consultado, el [estado de la respuesta](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/status) es el mismo para todos